# PHP for foreach

Tags: php, loops, foreach

I want to check for month in one year found in $month variable, if data found show the month (in number), if not found show '0'

```
<?php
$month = array(
    '2',
    '3',
    '4',
    '7',
    '12'
);

for ($i = 1; $i <= 12; $i++) {
    foreach($month as $key => $value) {
        if ($value == $i) {
            echo "$i" . "\n";
        }
        else {
            echo "0" . "\n";
        }
    }
}
```

from code above I get

```
0
0
0
0
0
2
0
0
0
0
0
3
0
0
0
0
0
4
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
7
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
12
```

if I add break 1 after else

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= 12; $i++) {
    foreach($month as $key => $value) {
        if ($value == $i) {
            echo "$i" . "\n";
        }
        else {
            echo "0" . "\n";
        }
        break 1;
    }
}
```

I got 12 result but not what I expected.

```
0
2
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
```

what I want is

```
0
2
3
4
0
0
7
0
0
0
0
12
```

If I able to get that result I want to put that these result in graph using chartjs, I know how to do that. I only want to know how to get these result, any help appriciate

Comment: Please remember to select an answer.  : )

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= 12; $i++) {
    if(in_array($i, $month)){
      echo "$i" . "\n";
    }else {
      echo "0" . "\n";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to print out only once per outer loop, not once per inner loop.  You want something more like:

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= 12; $i++) {
    $pos = 0;
    foreach($month as $key => $value) {
        if ($value == $i) {
            $pos = $i;
            break;
        }
    }
    echo "$pos" . "\n";
}
```

However, you can use builtin functions to do this more efficiently.  See the [in_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) function.